tsfresh - How do I assign computed feature values to all rows belonging to a group similar to pd.df.groupby.transform?
Tsfresh helps compute a lot of useful features from an input DataFrame (df). But I'm looking for something similar to pd.df.groupby.transform, which allows me to compute features for each group and helps assign, in a new column, the value of the computed feature to all rows belonging to that group like this:
groups = df.groupby(group_cols)
df["Std"] = groups["column"].transform('std') # Standard deviation as example

Pandas provides this groupby transform feature for only a few statistical features. I wish to use tsfresh to compute comprehensive features and assign the feature values to each row belonging to the group in a new column. How can I do this? I think it might be quite tedious if I manually use lambda functions for each feature I want to compute in pd methods for 1k+ features.
EDIT: The df concerned has three columns, including a column "group" with values 1 to 50. Each group has 10 rows associated with it, so there are 500 rows in total and group numbers 1 to 50 repeat 10 times each in sequence.

If I use tsfresh.extract_features(df_1, column_id = "group"), tsfresh returns a df like this with 50 rows only:

What I'm looking for is this, with the feature values assigned to all rows of each group and the total number of rows in the extracted feature df staying 500:


You need to be clear about what you're trying to do. Read the notice and ask questions. [mre]

@PandaKim I've added images of the actual and expected outputs, hope the question is clear now.

Read another announcement: why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors Please read the announcement before asking a question.
